# Working with django and mod_wsgi in Windows

Tags: python, windows, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I finished installing django on my Windows machine using Apache 2.2/Python 2.6/Django 1.3/mod_wsgi. It seems like everytime I change my Python code (such as settings.py), I need to restart Apache in order for changes to take effect.

I understood that using `WSGIRestrictEmbedded` should solve this issue but the docs for wsgi state about `WSGIRestrictEmbedded` that:

> This option does not exist on Windows,
>   or Apache 1.3 or any other
>   configuration where daemon mode is not
>   available.

What can I do then in order to avoid restarting Apache on every change?

Comment: WSGIRestrictEmbedded has got nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: don't use Apache in development. Use the built-in development server, or perhaps gunicorn.

Answer (score 2):

Read:

http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2009/02/source-code-reloading-with-modwsgi-on.html

It refers you to how to enable auto reload on Windows when using Apache/mod_wsgi.

Use of mod_wsgi is important when you need to test the multithread safety of your application and inbuilt development server is not multithreaded.

This auto reload mode should not be used on production systems.